# How to avoid "AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode" while running tests on Expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-maps, react-native-testing-library

I switched the react-native-maps provider to Google Maps on a React Native / Expo app. There's no issues when I run the app with Expo Go, but when opening the map on integration tests with react-native-testing library, I get the following error:

```
react-native-maps: AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps on iOS.
```

Stacktrace:

```
at error (node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/decorateMapComponent.js:25:13)
at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6097:18)
at updateFunctionComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10020:20)
at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11675:16)
at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15265:12)
at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15201:5)
at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15173:7)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14880:20)
at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2533:22)
at flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2512:5)
at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14314:7)
at dispatchSetState (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7235:16)
```

I do not understand why it is looking for directories in Xcode, even though running apps with Expo doesn't require Xcode. I also don't know why react-native-testing-libarary defaults to iOS and how to change that.

Thanks for helping!